# How can I know when the notification bar close

Tags: android

```
Object sbservice = getSystemService("statusbar");
Class<?> statusbarManager = Class.forName("android.app.StatusBarManager");
Method showsb;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expandNotificationsPanel");
} else {
    showsb = statusbarManager.getMethod("expand");
}
showsb.invoke(sbservice);
```

I use  this  to  expend  the  notification bar, But  my  activity is  fullScreen,
So  I must `getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)`

first,
After  close the notification  bar, I want to  set the actiivty fullScreen  again.
How can i do that ,thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to keep reference of your contentView then in re-add fullscreen flags and then call contentView.requestLayout()? I haven't tried it myself.